# MSSql server jpa spatial exception

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, spatial

Is it possible to use sql spatial data in jpa? I ve MS SQL Server 2014 Express Edition. I m trying to use spatial data as follows;

- maven (pom.xml) dependencies;

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.vividsolutions</groupId>
      <artifactId>jts</artifactId>
      <version>1.13</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-spatial</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
  </dependency>
  ```
- db dialect;

spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.sqlserver.SqlServer2008SpatialDialect

- entity definition;

  @Column(columnDefinition = "Geometry")
  private Point location;
- creation of data;

  SampleEntity se = new SampleEntity();
  se.setName("Sample1");
  se.setAge(30);
  GeometryFactory gf = new GeometryFactory(new PrecisionModel(), 4326);
  Point location1 = gf.createPoint(new Coordinate(0, 0, 4384));
  location1.setSRID(4326);
  se.setLocation(location1);
  System.out.println("LOCATION 1 SRID: " + se.getLocation().getSRID());
  System.out.println("geometry srid: " + gf.getSRID());
  sampleEntityRepository.save(se);

And i get following exception;

"Hibernate: insert into sample_entity (age, author, date_created, date_updated, location, name) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

2017-07-13 16:49:53.655  WARN 6600 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 6522, SQLState: S0001

2017-07-13 16:49:53.656 ERROR 6600 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geography":

System.ArgumentException: 24204: The spatial reference identifier (SRID) is not valid. The specified SRID must match one of the supported SRIDs displayed in the sys.spatial_reference_systems catalog view.

System.ArgumentException:

at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.set_Srid(Int32 value)

at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.Read(BinaryReader r)

at SqlGeography::.DeserializeValidate(IntPtr , Int32 , CClrLobContext* )
."

Is there any solution? Or, am i doing sth wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is due to specing incorrect dialect property:

> spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect

should be

> spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect

And whole string is: "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.sqlserver.SqlServer2008SpatialDialect"

Then, all should be working correctly. You can see it in the log of spring:

```
org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.sqlserver.SqlServer2008SpatialDialect
```